# Synonyms of "$x\leq y$ componentwise"

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

Consider two vectors $x$ and $y$ such that $x\leq y$ componentwise. Is there any "shorter" way for saying "$x\leq y$ componentwise"? For instance, are these acceptable synonyms:

- $x$ and $y$ are comparable
- $x$ and $y$ are partially orderable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those are not synonyms. There are many different (partial) orderings of vectors. Componentwise is not the only option. (other popular orderings would be by magnitude, or by non-zero entries, or using some non-obvious norm on the vector space).

But you can simply state something like "we use $\le$ to indicate the componentwise (partial) ordering of vectors" at the beginning of your text, and than only write "$x\le y$" in your calculations.